# zf2 - varibales not passing to view from controller

Tags: zend-framework2

Breaking my head since hours to find why this simple code is not working. I just want to pass variables to the .phtml file from my controller so I can render them the way I want but its simply not showing the values (or not passing the variables/value)

MyController Class:

```
public function indexAction(){
    $this->viewAction();
}

public function viewAction() {

    $view = new ViewModel(array('var1'=>'abc'));
    $view->setVariable('var1','abc');
    $view->var1 = 'abc';

    return $view;
}
```

in index.phtml I get nothing

```
echo "this is var1:$this->var1<br>"; //nothing
echo "this is var1:$var1<br>"; //nothing
```

it prints

> this is my var1:
>
> this is my var1:

`var_dump` returns `null` I know its very simple but

Dont know what mistake I am making here. Please help

Comment: Please show your full code. What you're describing is pretty much impossible ^^ More or less implies that this is not the correct ViewModel that you're getting.

Comment: Is 'index.phtml' a layout file by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the code you've posted and the filename you've posted are correct, then this is your problem.

You assign a `viewAction()`, so the action template to be rendered is `/modulename/controllername/view.phtml`. As you can see it's `view.phtml` but you have posted `index.phtml`. This won't work :)

**Update**

Your `indexAction()` doesn't **`return`** anything, therefore an empty `ViewModel` will be used by default. Given you code you should do `return $this->viewAction()`, but I'd argue that this kind of code-separation is a really bad practice.

Comment: I am really sorry for not providing the updated code in first place. I am actually calling viewAction from indexAction(); updated code. Sorry for that incomplete information

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper you're not returning anything from your `indexAction()` ;) This results in an empty `ViewModel` being used per default. You'd need to do `return $this->viewAction()` but then again separating code like that is a pretty bad habbit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually return an array with key/values

```
return array('var1'=>'abc');
```

then I use the variable in the view as $var1.